# Can not update Fastapi

Tags: python-3.x, fastapi

When I run put from FastAPI docs with the following code I get `500 Error: Internal Server Error`  the terminal shows

```
{'type': 'missing', 'loc': ('response', 'id'), 'msg': 'Field required', 'input': {'data': <app.models.post.post_models.Post object at 0x0000019CAA6C4310>, 'message': 'C\u1eadp nh\u1eadp bài \u0111\u0103ng có 1 thành công'}, 'url': 'https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.4/v/missing'}
  {'type': 'missing', 'loc': ('response', 'type'), 'msg': 'Field required', 'input': {'data': <app.models.post.post_models.Post object at 0x0000019CAA6C4310>, 'message': 'C\u1eadp nh\u1eadp bài \u0111\u0103ng có 1 thành công'}, 'url': 'https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.4/v/missing'}
  {'type': 'missing', 'loc': ('response', 'create_uid'), 'msg': 'Field required', 'input': {'data': <app.models.post.post_models.Post object at 0x0000019CAA6C4310>, 'message': 'C\u1eadp nh\u1eadp bài \u0111\u0103ng có 1 thành công'}, 'url': 'https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.4/v/missing'}
  {'type': 'missing', 'loc': ('response', 'create_date'), 'msg': 'Field required', 'input': {'data': <app.models.post.post_models.Post object at 0x0000019CAA6C4310>, 'message': 'C\u1eadp nh\u1eadp bài \u0111\u0103ng có 1 thành công'}, 'url': 'https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.4/v/missing'}
  {'type': 'missing', 'loc': ('response', 'view_post'), 'msg': 'Field required', 'input': {'data': <app.models.post.post_models.Post object at 0x0000019CAA6C4310>, 'message': 'C\u1eadp nh\u1eadp bài \u0111\u0103ng có 1 thành công'}, 'url': 'https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.4/v/missing'}
  {'type': 'missing', 'loc': ('response', 'is_published'), 'msg': 'Field required', 'input': {'data': <app.models.post.post_models.Post object at 0x0000019CAA6C4310>, 'message': 'C\u1eadp nh\u1eadp bài \u0111\u0103ng có 1 thành công'}, 'url': 'https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.4/v/missing'}
  {'type': 'missing', 'loc': ('response', 'rate'), 'msg': 'Field required', 'input': {'data': <app.models.post.post_models.Post object at 0x0000019CAA6C4310>, 'message': 'C\u1eadp nh\u1eadp bài \u0111\u0103ng có 1 thành công'}, 'url': 'https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.4/v/missing'}
```

**Model:**

```
class Post(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'post'

    id = Column(BIGINT, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    type = Column(VARCHAR, nullable=False)
    content_post = Column(TEXT, nullable=True)
    description_post = Column(TEXT, nullable=True)
    create_uid = Column(BIGINT, nullable=False)
    create_date = Column(TIMESTAMP, nullable=False)
    view_post = Column(BIGINT, nullable=True)
    is_published = Column(Boolean, nullable=False)
    rate = Column(BIGINT, nullable=False)
    image_filename = Column(VARCHAR, nullable=True)
    image_url = Column(VARCHAR, nullable=True)
```

**Schema**

```
class PostResponse(BaseModel):
    id: int
    type: str
    content_post: str | None = None
    description_post: str | None = None
    create_uid: int
    create_date: datetime.datetime
    view_post: int
    is_published: bool
    rate: int
    image_filename: str | None = None
    image_url: str | None = None
```

**Service**

```
def update_post(db: Session, post: PostResponse):
   post_query = db.query(Post).filter(or_(Post.id == post.id)).first()
   if post_query is None:
       raise HTTPException(status_code=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND,
                            detail=f"Bản ghi có {id} không tồn tại")
   else:
       try:
           post_query.id = post.id
           post_query.type = post.type
           post_query.content_post = post.content_post
           post_query.description_post = post.description_post
           post_query.create_uid = post.create_uid
           post_query.create_date = post.create_date
           post_query.view_post = post.view_post
           post_query.is_published = post.is_published
           post_query.rate = post.rate
           db.commit()
           return {
               "data": post_query,
               "message": f"Cập nhập bài đăng có {post.id} thành công"
           }
       except Exception as e:
            db.rollback()
            raise HTTPException(status_code=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST,
                                detail=e)
```

**router**

```
@router.post('/update-post', response_model=PostResponse)
def update_post(post: PostResponse, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    return post_service.update_post(db, post)
```

My request:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "type": "Python",
  "content_post": "string",
  "description_post": "string",
  "create_uid": 0,
  "create_date": "2023-11-09T01:50:54.344Z",
  "view_post": 0,
  "is_published": true,
  "rate": 1
}
```

Comment: You're returning a database model object, which can't be automagically mapped to a Pydantic object unless you tell Pydantic that it can load the properties from attributes instead of a dict lookup. See `from_attributes` in `model_config` and `ConfigDict`: https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/concepts/models/#arbitrary-class-instances

Comment: Yeah i delete response_model=PostResponse then the code works but data : {} will fix solution "data": PostResponse.model_validate(post_query)  + model_config = ConfigDict(from_attributes=True)

Comment: Don't delete `PostResponse` - you want to use that response, but you have to add a `model_config` field to your `PostResponse` object to let it load parameters from attributes instead of only through dict lookups.

Comment: If I don't delete it, I will get an error on the post